# I'm learning C language but I cannot run the 'y' to continue the program

Tags: c

Here i get the answers for vowels but not for continue it says error for the continue and also for break.

```
#include < stdio.h >
  main() {
    char c, d;
    printf("say your word to find the vowels\n");
    scanf("%c", & c);
    if (c == 'a' || c == 'A' || c == 'e' || c == 'E' || c == 'i' || c == 'I' || c == 'o' || c == 'O' || c == 'u' || c == 'U')
      printf("you got a vowel\n");
    else
      printf("cool no vowel word\n");
    printf("continue\n");
    printf("(y/n)\n");
    scanf("%c", & d);
    if (d == 'y' || d == 'Y')
      continue;
    else
      break;
    return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (d == 'y' || d == 'Y')
  continue;  // where?
else
  break;     // what?
```

You have nothing to `continue` or `break` in your main function.

Both `continue` and `break` only make sense within a loop, so you should add a `while(true)` loop around the code in `main()` to repeat the whole thing until the user decides to quit.

Answer (score 0):

Continue and break works in the loop block.. but here you have not added them in loop. Put the whole if block in the `while(1)` and it will work

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    int d;
    while (1) {
        printf("say your word to find the vowels\n");
        scanf("%c", &c);

        if (c == 'a' || c == 'A' || c == 'e' || c == 'E' || c == 'i' || c == 'I' || c == 'o' || c == 'O' || c == 'u' || c == 'U')
            printf("you got a vowel\n");
        else
            printf("cool no vowel word\n");

        printf("To continue enter 1\n");
        scanf("%d", &d);

        if (d == 1)
            continue;
        else
            break;
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

Check the continue and break statement syntax in the following link.

https://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-for-loop-while-loop-break-and-continue

Comment: Would `while (true)` be better?

Comment: Sure! if the compiler is comfortable with it.

Comment: okay.. I would be happy if you help me out. I just used some online beautifier.